# How to trim part of git rev-parse output from windows slave

Tags: windows, groovy, git-rev-parse

I have the below output from my `jenkinsfile.groovy` (running on `windows` slave):
command:

`def commitHash = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD").trim()`

`commitHash` content:

`c:\jenkins-slave\workspace\test-K5I54FOWDXJU7QWEX2YF4ZSWVNSFITDVMLAIK3SVMG3V4JJM2QHA>git rev-parse HEAD  123456`

How can I get from it only `123456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [JENKINS-44569](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44569)

```
def getCommandOutput(cmd) {
    if (isUnix()){
         return sh(returnStdout:true , script: '#!/bin/sh -e\n' + cmd).trim()
     } else{
       stdout = bat(returnStdout:true , script: cmd).trim()
       result = stdout.readLines().drop(1).join(" ")       
       return result
    } 
}
```

That or adding `@echo off` to the command, as [seen here](http://blog.kostecky.cz/2018/08/jenkins-pipeline-calls-cmd-command.html) (and commented below)

```
env.gitcurrent= \
bat(returnStdout: true, script: "@echo off | git --git-dir=${WORKSPACE}\\.git rev-parse HEAD 2> nul || echo githash").trim()
```

Comment: I will try it. I've found another reference for it here: http://blog.kostecky.cz/2018/08/jenkins-pipeline-calls-cmd-command.html

Comment: @arielma Good point. I have included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add @.

**def commitHash = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "@git rev-parse HEAD").trim()**

This fixed my issue.